# Using AWS Elastic Beanstalk with a Java/BlazeDS/Spring application

Tags: java, actionscript-3, spring, amazon-web-services, blazeds

Is it possible to deploy my Spring/BlazeDS/Java application to elastic beanstalk? I'm using MyEclipse and built a Java Web Project with the required jar files etc. Do you need to specifically create an AWS Java Web Project - reason I ask is the options to include the BlazeDS files aren't there - so I'm wondering if Spring / BlazeDS is even supported? By default the turnkey blazeds runs through Port 8400 - so I imagine there are some additional tasks required to configure the endpoints to work through port 80?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlazeDS is not a standalone application, it consists from a bunch of jar files which should be added to your web application. You will also need to declare a servlet in the web.xml file. I wrote an article a couple of years ago how to add the blazeds jar files to a java web application (and what to configure), you can take a look [here](http://cornelcreanga.com/2009/01/blazeds-lcds-and-integration-with-existing-application/).

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. The project is completed so I know how to configure blazeds with a java project, what I'm asking is whether or not anyone has successfully deployed a BlazeDS/Flex project to Elastic Beanstalk. Google App Engine requires a fair bit of modification (such as recompiling flex messaging jar) due to sandbox restriction - so I'm trying to find some info about AWS. Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried myself to run an application but one of my colleagues did:http://www.riaspace.com/2011/07/running-lcds-blazeds-in-the-cloud-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: There's unfortunately no information here about if a blaze push application is possible. This is Technically correct, blazeds is possible... I should have indicated "push" in my question. Some articles mention needing to recompile flex.messaging from the blazeds source code - I'd settle for any proof of a push based blazeds running on aws.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example. Will be trying something similar over the next few weeks.

http://www.riaspace.com/tag/aws/

Comment: Are you answering yes or answering no to the question of whether it's possible? I can't tell.